# Seeking RedMine plugin example: to add a custom spinner control to the ISSUE screen

Tags: database, user-interface, plugins, redmine

Seeking an example RedMine Plugin or tutorial to add a spinner control to the RedMine ISSUES UI page.

This has two parts: (1) adding the spinner control to the RedMine page UI and (2) adding a new column in the RedMine DB to store the spinner's input value.

http://www.redmine.org/  *Redmine is a flexible project management web application. Written using the Ruby on Rails framework, it is cross-platform and cross-database. Redmine is open source and released under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2 (GPL).*

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinner_%28computing%29).

In your plugin, simply create a new custom field format (inherit from `IntFormat` which is defined in `lib/redmine/field_format.rb`) and override the `edit_tag` method to render your control.

Then in Redmine, with your plugin installed, you can just create a custom issue field using the newly defined format. This field will then be rendered the way you want. There is no need to patch Redmine's Views or add a new column to the database for this.